# Unable to get the correct Dirac delta Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I wrote

```
ω = 2 πf; τ = 1/f;

FourierTransform[β*Cos[ωt], t, ω]
```

I expected

constant x DiracDelta(-omega1+omega)+constant x DiracDelta(omega1+omega)

the answer was

```
Sqrt[π/2] β x Cos[ωt] DiracDelta[πf]
```

How do I express the answer in the form of the 2 DiracDelta?

Comment: I mean DiracDelta

Comment: You can [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/143706/edit) your question to fix your mistakes, by clicking the "edit" button under your question, or clicking the link I gave.

Answer (score 3):

There are different definitions of the Fourier transform.

```
FourierTransform[b*Cos[2 Pi f t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {0, -1}]
```

gives the answer you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, as it turns out in this case I used 0 -1, 1 -1 did not give me the correct FT expression that I wanted.